# Change VsCode terminal tabs icon and color with the cli

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to be able to change the color & icon of my terminal tabs & colors with the cli.

[image]

This could be the result
[image]

The reason of it would be to use the [restore terminals](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EthanSK.restore-terminals) extension, and then automatically set the a different icon and color of **each** terminal.

But I can't find it through the documentation, is it somehow doable?

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2qkv.png)?

Comment: @TimothyG. Exactly, I did update my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone is still interested, this can be done.
At least right now you can specify the profile for the terminal in the extension settings:

```
"restoreTerminals.terminals": [
    {
      "profile": "Coverage",
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "Coverage",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "profile": "Server",
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "Server",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

So you can actually create a profile for each terminal you want like so:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Coverage": {
      "path": ["D:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
      "icon": "beaker",
      "color": "terminal.ansiGreen"
    },
    "Server": {
      "path": ["D:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
      "icon": "server",
      "color": "terminal.ansiMagenta"
    }
  },
```

And done:

[image: Terminals]

Comment: Thx for the answer, also saw this was doable and this [extension](https://github.com/fabiospampinato/vscode-terminals) already did have implemented that feature

Comment: not working for me on windows...

Answer (score 3):

In your settings.json file you can specify the `icon` and `color` of the icon within the profile.  For example:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash", //what icon to use
            "color": "terminal.ansiGreen" //color of icon
        }
    },
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
```

Using that extension you linked to yields a result like this (using the example json settings they list in their extension documentation):

[image: Icons]

It looks like the extension uses whatever your default terminal profile is (actually looking at its source code, it doesn't even know what the default profile it, is just calls [VS Code API commands to spawn new terminals](https://github.com/EthanSK/restore-terminals-vscode/blob/6dc188f9f9677feef22f4f8f41f3e71a6f64672d/src/restoreTerminals.ts#L93)), and applies the settings of said profile, so you will be limited to only the one color/icon.

Comment: Thx for your answer, The purpose of my question was to be able to change each icon and color, api should be yellow, cloud blue, .... 
I did update my question to be more precise of what I do try to archive.

Answer (score 0):

> , The purpose of my question was to be able to change each icon and color, api should be yellow, cloud blue, .... I did update my question to be more precise of what I do try to archive.

If it is doable, that won't be by VSCode itself, but by an extension.

"Assign unique/random color/icon to terminal tab on creation" ([`microsoft/vscode` issue 127951](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127951)) is clear:

> closing as an extension could do it

The OP adds:

> to make it doable we first need to understand how to change the color through the api

This is followed by [issue 128228](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128228) and implemented in [PR 130123 "Finalize terminal color API"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/130123)

Comment: Adding a random color could be, for sure, done by an extension. And, in fact, I want it to be done by the [restore terminal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EthanSK.restore-terminals) plugin. But to make it doable we first need to understand how to change the color through the api, so I do not think the refuse of that specific feature request is a proper answer to my question, but I may be missing something here :)

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet Would [issue 128228](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128228) and [PR 130123](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/130123)