# Is there a way to specify task icon and color when running the "nx run" command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nrwl-nx

I found the functionality to manually assign an icon and a color to a specific task in Visual Studio Code after I start it on the "nx console" sidebar with the "play icon" button. Can you somehow assign the icon and color you want to see to the nx command itself, so you don't have to set it up manually every time by right clicking the task?

This is what I see when I click on "serve":

[image: icon and color not specified]

This is what I want to see after clicking on "serve":

[image: icon and color specified]

Note: I moved both panels to one corner so they are next to each other

Answer (score 4):

You have to have a `tasks.json` configured for the project. You probably already have one, but if you don't, the file goes under `.vscode/`. The bit that controls the appearance of this icon is this:

```json
{
  // ...
  "tasks": [
    {
      // ...
      "icon": {
        "id": "database",
        "color": "terminal.ansiGreen"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use autocomplete to explore the available colours and icons.

Comment: This helps with the general direction of the solution, but I still don't know how to map the nx commands so when I run them they become automatically, for instance, to be green and to have the database icon

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297141/change-vscode-terminal-tabs-icon-and-color-with-the-cli

Comment: List of supported icon ids https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels. Vscode json validation can complain that labels listed there are invalid, but they actually work.